# .htaccess create Redirect rule from rewriterule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am replacing an old open source solution with my own, however I need all old links to work with my new thing. Using  RewriteRule creates a lot of issues with relative path of images and links, plus we want to promote the new url.

old url:
www.website.com/folder1/folder2/number/

new url :
www.anotherwebsite.com/folder1/index2.php?f=show&e=number

where 'number' is an 'id' that I use in my program.

Old solution has this .htaccess entry, so if possible I need to account for different entry formats as well

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        SetEnv MY_REWRITE 1

        Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
        RewriteEngine on

        RewriteRule ^.*\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ - [L,PT]

        RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ ?CategoryID=$1 [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)(/([0-9]+))?(/([a-zA-Z_]+))?/?$ index.php?View=$1&EntryID=$3&Msg=$5 [QSA,L]
        RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)(/([0-9]+))?(/([0-9]+))?(/([a-zA-Z_]+))?/?$ index.php?View=$1&CategoryID=$3&EntryID=$5&Msg=$7 [QSA,L]


</IfModule>
```

I have considered redirecting everything to a php page, that will just get the url that was originally requested and then send a header information with redirect to new tool, however I want to avoid doing a hacky job, and redirect things with .htaccess if possible.

Comment: So you want to redirect `www.website.com/folder1/folder2/number/` to `www.anotherwebsite.com/folder1/index2.php?f=show&e=number`?

Comment: yes. And take care of all the other cases that might not match the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new rule for this redirect as your **very first rule**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   SetEnv MY_REWRITE 1

   Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(folder1)/folder2/([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.anotherwebsite.com/$1/index2.php?f=show&e=$2 [L,NC,R=301,QSA]

   RewriteRule ^.*\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ - [L,PT]
   RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ ?CategoryID=$1 [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)(/([0-9]+))?(/([a-zA-Z_]+))?/?$ index.php?View=$1&EntryID=$3&Msg=$5 [QSA,L]

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)(/([0-9]+))?(/([0-9]+))?(/([a-zA-Z_]+))?/?$ index.php?View=$1&CategoryID=$3&EntryID=$5&Msg=$7 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Using rewriteRule does not work because it creates a lot of broken dependencies, and we want to actually redirect to a different website instead of just making it transparent.

Comment: Clarify what you mean by `it creates a lot of broken dependencies`? Are you still trying to redirect `www.website.com/folder1/folder2/number/` to new URL?

Comment: by using rewrite rule, a user that's going to website.com/fold/kb/123 will see the content of anotherwebsite.com/kb?f=show&e=123, while the URL will stay the same. Which means that when the anotherwebsite.com uses a relative path in one of its links, the browser will resolve path to website.com/folder1/folder2/number/somepathfromnewserver/stuff.jpg , which will just give 404 because files are not there. What I need is  a Redirect 301 rule that will send user to new website instead of just look different.

Comment: **by using rewrite rule, a user that's going to website.com/fold/kb/123 will see the content of anotherwebsite.com/kb?f=show&e=123, while the URL will stay the same.** This part isn't right as my suggested rule is using `R=301` that will **change URL in the browser** to `www.anotherwebsite.com/folder1/index2.php?f=show&e=number`

Comment: Oops, sorry. Forgot to add that part.